# Javascript Pop Up box on if statement

Tags: php, javascript, popup, messagebox

My code is as follows:

```
//Input Validations 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `email` = '$insp_email' LIMIT 1" ); 
$exist = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
    if ($exist !==false ) { 
       $errmsg_arr[] = 'That Email is already registered.';
       $errflag = true;
       }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `login` = '$user_name' LIMIT 1" ); 
$exist = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
    if ($exist !==false ) { 
       $errmsg_arr[] = 'That Username is already registered.';
       $errflag = true;
       }

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG_ARR'] = $errmsg_arr;
            $_SESSION['ERROR'] = 'Yes';
    session_write_close();
    header("location: accountinfo.php");
    exit();
}
```

If there are any input validations from the registration page, the user will be directed back to the registration page.  What I want to do is when they are redirected back, $_SESSION['ERROR'] will = True.  When and only when that is = True, do I want a popup box to display a error message.  I the code for the popup message. I just can't figure out how to get it to load only on the if $_SESSION['ERROR'] == 'True'

```
<script language="javascript">
alert('<?= $s ?>')
</script>
```

That code will display a message with a php variable.  I need help getting the message to display only when the $_SESSION['ERROR'] equals 'True'

Thank you!

Comment: `alert()` boxes for form errors are annoying as hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your register page:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['ERROR']) && $_SESSION['ERROR']) { ?>
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
//<!--
   alert("I am an error Message.");
//-->
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Of course, it won't work if JS is disabled.  You could add in a noscript tag as well and at least display the error message in the same fashion.